# Using wildcards in SQL IN operator

Tags: mysql, wildcard, sql-in

Structure:

```
table
c1 c2
1  test
1  test2
2  test
2  test3
3  test4
```

SQL:

```
SELECT c1 FROM table WHERE c2 in ("test3","test4")
```

What I want:

```
SELECT c1 FROM table WHERE c2 in ("%3","%st4")
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Does this even make sense? Why would you do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT c1 FROM table WHERE (c2 like "%3") or (c2 like "%st4")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach just to follow the logic you have in your question:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aca65e/2

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE c2 REGEXP '.*3$|.*st4$';
```

But keep in mind that solution

```
SELECT c1 FROM table WHERE (c2 like "%3") or (c2 like "%st4")
```

provided by @splash58 could be much faster if `c2` column is indexed.